# Concept question: Is it the same when you say "Solve the following equations:" with "Solve the following systems of equations"?

Tags: systems-of-equations

I am creating a worksheet and I want to include solving for solutions.

My initial instruction was

"Solve the following equations:"

1. $a^3 = 3$
2. $2x+y=4$,
   $4x^2+y^2=1$

Should I need to divide the worksheet into two or it's okay to use the same instruction for both of the given?

Comment: What do you mean divide the worksheet into two? The first equation $a^3=3$ is one _question_. The second _question_ is solving a system of equations (two) with two varibale, which is also a _single_ question.

Comment: @eminem Yes, that's what I meant with "divide the worksheet into two parts". Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Divide in two. You can solve an equation without it's sister; you'll just get infinite solutions.